# PyTorch - AssertionError: Size mismatch between tensors

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch

I am trying to adapt a Pytorch script that was created for linear regression. It was originally written to take in a set of random values(created with np.random) as features and targets.

I have now created a dataframe of actual data for analysis:

```
df = pd.read_csv('file_name.csv')
```

The df looks like this:

```
      X1     X2     X3     X4    X5   X6   X7  X8    Y1     Y2
0    0.98  514.5  294.0  110.25  7.0   2  0.0   0  15.55  21.33
1    0.98  514.5  294.0  110.25  7.0   3  0.0   0  15.55  21.33
2    0.98  514.5  294.0  110.25  7.0   4  0.0   0  15.55  21.33
3    0.98  514.5  294.0  110.25  7.0   5  0.0   0  15.55  21.33
4    0.90  563.5  318.5  122.50  7.0   2  0.0   0  20.84  28.28
```

...and I am currently extracting just two columns(X1 and X2) as my features, and one column(Y1) as my targets, like this:

```
x = df[['X1', 'X2']]
y = df['Y1']
```

So features look like this:

```
      X1     X2
0    0.98  514.5
1    0.98  514.5
2    0.98  514.5
3    0.98  514.5
4    0.90  563.5
```

and targets look like this:

```
        Y1
0      15.55
1      15.55
2      15.55
3      15.55
4      20.84
```

However, when I attempt to convert the features (X1 and X1) and targets(Y1) to tensors, in order to feed them to the NN, the code fails at the line:

dataset = TensorDataset(x_tensor_flat, y_tensor_flat)

I get the error:

```
line 45, in <module> dataset = TensorDataset(x_tensor, y_tensor)
AssertionError: Size mismatch between tensors
```

There's clearly some shaping issue at play, but I can't work out what.
I have tried to flatten as well as transposing the tensors, but I get the same error.
Any help would be hugely appreciated.

Here's the full section of code that is causing the issue:

```
import pandas as pd
import torch
import torch.optim as optim
import torch.nn as nn
from torch.utils.data import Dataset, TensorDataset, DataLoader
from torch.utils.data.dataset import random_split

device = 'cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu'


df = pd.read_csv('file_name.csv')
x = df[['X1', 'X2']]
y = df['Y1']


x_tensor = torch.from_numpy(np.array(x)).float()
y_tensor = torch.from_numpy(np.array(y)).float()


train_loader = DataLoader(dataset=train_dataset, batch_size=10)
val_loader = DataLoader(dataset=val_dataset, batch_size=10)


class ManualLinearRegression(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.linear = nn.Linear(2, 1)

    def forward(self, x):
        return self.linear(x)

def make_train_step(model, loss_fn, optimizer):
    def train_step(x, y):
        model.train()
        yhat = model(x)
        loss = loss_fn(y, yhat)
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        return loss.item()
    return train_step


torch.manual_seed(42)

model = ManualLinearRegression().to(device) 
loss_fn = nn.MSELoss(reduction='mean')
optimizer = optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=1e-1)
train_step = make_train_step(model, loss_fn, optimizer)

n_epochs = 50
training_losses = []
validation_losses = []
print(model.state_dict())

for epoch in range(n_epochs):
    batch_losses = []
    for x_batch, y_batch in train_loader:
        x_batch = x_batch.to(device)
        y_batch = y_batch.to(device)
        loss = train_step(x_batch, y_batch)
        batch_losses.append(loss)
    training_loss = np.mean(batch_losses)
    training_losses.append(training_loss)

    with torch.no_grad():
        val_losses = []
        for x_val, y_val in val_loader:
            x_val = x_val.to(device)
            y_val = y_val.to(device)
            model.eval()
            yhat = model(x_val)
            val_loss = loss_fn(y_val, yhat).item()
            val_losses.append(val_loss)
        validation_loss = np.mean(val_losses)
        validation_losses.append(validation_loss)

    print(f"[{epoch+1}] Training loss: {training_loss:.3f}\t Validation loss: {validation_loss:.3f}")

print(model.state_dict())
```

Comment: Just as an additional piece of info: If I do NOT flatten the tensors, I get the error: "ValueError: Sum of input lengths does not equal the length of the input dataset!"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is with how you have called the `random_split` function. Note that it takes lengths as input, not the percentage or ratio of the split. The error is about the same, i.e., the sum of lengths (80+20) that you have specified is not the same as the length of data (5).

The below code snippet should fix your problem. Also, you do not need to flatten tensors... I think.

```
dataset = TensorDataset(x_tensor, y_tensor)
val_size = int(len(dataset)*0.2)
train_size = len(dataset)- int(len(dataset)*0.2)
train_dataset, val_dataset = random_split(dataset, [train_size, val_size])
```

Comment: Thank you. This allowed the code to run a bit further. However, I now get the error -  "UserWarning: Using a target size (torch.Size([10, 1])) that is different to the input size (torch.Size([10])). This will likely lead to incorrect results due to broadcasting. Please ensure they have the same size." The code does run, but I get NaN values for every calculation. The batch sizes are both 10, so I am not sure what this means.

Comment: @HexNeural That is another problem and would require more details/new questions. However, I can provide limited help in the comments. 
1. Your labels are (10,) and network output is (10,1). That is why you get warnings. In this specific case, you can ignore the warning as there won't be a broadcast error or fix by reshaping either of the tensors. 

 2. You might be getting NaN because the learning rate (LR) is high. Try reducing the LR, or even better try running just the forward pass and see what happens. You shouldn't be getting Nan on only forward if it is due to the LR.

Comment: Update: It turns out, if I reduce the learning rate to something extremely small (like lr=1e-9), then the script actually does produce an output and not just NaN. Thank you again. @Umang Gupta

Comment: Glad it worked! Your data ranges look weird (large numbers). It might be nice to do some preprocessing (eg. standard normalization and min-max scaling) before passing it to the neural network

Answer (score 1):

The problem with this is that without a batch size to specify all your dimensions are different so to fix this

```py
dataset = CustomDataset(x_tensor_flat, y_tensor_flat) # Use this should work equally well
```

If you still want to use TensorDataset

```py
dataset = TensorDataset(x_tensor_flat.unsqueeze(0), y_tensor_flat.unsqueeze(0)) # Make sure they have the same batch dimensions (e.g (1, 100) , (1, 20) # can be different as long as batch matches)
```

Comment: If I use: dataset = TensorDataset(x_tensor_flat.unsqueeze(0), y_tensor_flat.unsqueeze(0)), I get the error: "ValueError: Sum of input lengths does not equal the length of the input dataset!